# Host homepage on a different server than the rest of site

Tags: dns

Is it possible to host one page of a website (example.com/index.html) on a different server than the remainder of the site (example.com/blog/ and etc.)? Are there ways to manage this through DNS settings? An .htaccess file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is, not really. A DNS entry maps a **hostname** (example.com) to an IP address. The **path** part of the url (/index.html) is not part of the hostname, and is only contained inside the http headers.

The general practice for this kind of situation is to use a proxy or load balancer which will send requests to different servers depending on the request path.

If it really needs to go to two different places without a central load balancer, then you probably need a unique subdomain for each site.